# Bottle serve file from a different directory

Tags: python, bottle

I have simple Bottle application which serves a page for /Startpage location. The index.html page is located under /banana folder and the banana folder is located under the same folder where my views.py exist.

When I try this, its unable to find the page and throws internal server error

```
@app.wrap_app.route('/StartPage',method='GET')
def doStartPage():
    return template('banana/index.html')
```

How can I refer my /banana folder in my template?

Answer (score 0):

The bottle [FAQ](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/faq.html#template-not-found-in-mod-wsgi-mod-python) specifies the following

> Bottle searches in ./ and ./views/ for templates. In a mod_python or mod_wsgi environment, the working directory (./) depends on your Apache settings. You should add an absolute path to the template search path so bottle searches the right paths.

You will need to add the `bananas` folder to the `TEMPLATE_PATH`

```
base_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
bananas_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'bananas')
bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, bananas_path)
```

EDIT: Improved the answer with [Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton)'s suggestion to use paths relative to where the code is located.

Comment: Rather than hard code an absolute path, better to calculate it dynamically relative to where the code is located by determining the base directory using ``os.path.dirname(__file__)`` and then adding the relative path on the end. That is, use this approach in setting ``bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH``.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

Create a rooting rule for your folder :

```
@route('/banana/<filepath:path>')
def file_stac(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root="./banana")
```

And then, you only need to refer to this folder like this :

```
@route('/foo')
def bar():
    return template('banana/foo.tpl')
```

You can do the same for as many folder as you want, and this is usefull for serving css/js files inside a template (on your template, you can then do :

```
<link href="banana/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

Almost 8 years late, but I did as follow for my issue, but replacing my folder with yours:

```
@route(/banana/<filename>)
def banana(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./views/banana/')
```